# SQL merging three SELECT JOINS into one table

Tags: sql, join, concatenation

Hockey APP. Have to query all rows in TABLE 2 and display the players NAME instead of the player ids

*Note: new to stack overflow sorry for the format

---

table 1: players

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║ id | fname | lname  ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ 1 | Jason | McFee   ║
║ 2 | John | Smith    ║
║ 3 | Jack | Doe      ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

---

table 2: events_goals

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║ id  g_id  a1_id  a2_id  ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1  2  3             ║
║ 2   3  1  2             ║
║ 3   2  1  3             ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

---

What i am trying to do is take each row from events_goals and return it with the matching player names

WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH: players names executed out, i dont need the (#) beside the name i just put that there to reference the player id

Table 3

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id  goal  assist1  assist2                     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  Jason McFee(1)  John SMith(2)  Jack Doe(3)  ║
║ 2  Jack Doe(3)  Jason McFee(1)  John Smith(2)  ║
║ 3  John Smith(2)  Jason McFee(1)  Jack Doe (3) ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

WHAT I HAVE DONE

I tried a bunch of different queries and this is the best one thus far

```
SELECT players.fname AS GFN, 
       players.lname AS GLN 
FROM   events_goals 
       LEFT JOIN players 
              ON events_goals.g_id = players.playerid
```

This returns:

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ GFN  GLN      ║
╠═══════════════╣
║ Jason  McFee  ║
║ Jack  Doe     ║
║ John  Smith   ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

I can run the same code for Assists1 and Assists 2, but I am having trouble joining all 3 SELECT queries together successfully, ideally i would like to join the first and last name column into 1 cell but I can live without that, main thing is getting all the IDs converted to names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` table `players` thrice on table `event_goals` since there are three columns that are dependent with `players.id`.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', b.fname, b.lname) goal,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', c.fname, c.lname) assist1,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', d.fname, d.lname) assist2
FROM    event_goals a
        INNER JOIN players b
            ON a.g_id = b.id
        INNER JOIN players c
            ON a.a1_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN players d
            ON a.a2_id = d.id
ORDER   BY a.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b98e/3)